# How can I prepare to install elementary OS before installing a new hard drive?

Tags: software-installation

I am installing a new hard drive in my HP computer and would like to do a clean install of elementary OS—and not have Windows on there anymore. How can I make a DVD of elementary OS now, while my computer is still operational, and then install it on the new hard drive? I am a basic user.

Answer (score 1):

Go to elementary.io and download the Image file(.iso). Once it is downloaded just right click on the .iso file and windows should give you the option to burn it to dvd. You can then boot from that dvd to test out and or install elementary OS. It comes up with a very easy to follow prompt to install the OS. You may need to look elsewhere to find out how to boot the DVD though, that depends on the maker of your computer, and if it has bios or UEFI.

Comment: As a note, we strongly recommend installing using a USB drive instead of a DVD, as flash storage is much faster than a DVD. Other than that, this is pretty thorough!